# Unit Test viewRenderer's renderScript method (Zend Framework 1.12)

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework

In the setup below, there is
a controller action (index/hello) that renders a view script different than the default
`index/instead-of-hello.phtml` instead of `index/hello.phtml`

```
public function helloAction()
{
    $this->renderScript('index/instead-of-hello.phtml');
}
```

I would like to **unit test** that the action actually **renders** `index/instead-of-hello.phtml`

```
public function testHelloAction()
{
    $params = array('action' => 'hello', 'controller' => 'Index', 'module' => 'default');
    $urlParams = $this->urlizeOptions($params);
    $url = $this->url($urlParams);
    $this->dispatch($url);
    $renderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $this->assertEquals('index/instead-of-hello.phtml', $renderer->getViewScript());
}
```

This test fails since the `renderer->getViewScript()` returns the script that would be rendered by default and not the one that was actually rendered.

```
1) IndexControllerTest::testHelloAction
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-index/instead-of-hello.phtml
+index/hello.phtml
```

How could I successfully test that the script `index/instead-of-hello.phtml` was actually rendered?

Zend Framework 1.12 is used on the [example above](https://github.com/dbaltas/zend-framework1.12-playground/commit/49fb229943f1a6c470703693eda669b4c402b2da).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$this->render('index/instead-of-hello.phtml');
```

here is the explanation from Documentation:

```
$this->renderScript()
```

> When using this method, the ViewRenderer does no autodetermination of
>   the script name, but instead directly passes the $script argument
>   directly to the view object's render() method.

Comment: Thanks! Just to comment that the folder and the file extension are not needed. This works: $this->render('instead-of-hello')